# Update Discovery Service endpoint in Topology Manager

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager, discovery-service

We need to update our Discovery Service endpoint in Topology Manager as we need to map our services to a new domain name. Except the domain name, everything else is same.

In above scenario, can we update the Discovery Service endpoint in Topology Manager without destroying it?

If we need to destroy Topology Manager, do I need to republish all my content which was published earlier with the old endpoint?

Answer (score 6):

If the URL of your Discovery Service changes, you can use the `Set-TtmCdEnvironment` cmdlet to update the URL in Topology Manager.

No need to destroy things. :-)

BTW: publish state is still stored in the CM DB, so *if* you would recreate the Topology Manager DB, there would not be a need to republish anything.

Comment: Thanks Rick, will validate and update my findings